# ora-01002 fetch out of sequence for unobvious reasons

Tags: asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a procedure and its related function which binds the output to a `datatable`.But while filling the datatable I get error as below. Also checked on google but nothing working

> ora-01002 fetch out of sequence

Here is the link for the procedure

[link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=80de10cd6b7187220e07122879d49678)

Also below is the code for filling the datatable

```html
public DataTable GetSPANByMZ(string USERTYPE, string SPANTYPE, string MZONE, string OPERATIONTYPE)
        {
            DataTable dtSPAN = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                DBObject ObjDBObject = new DBObject(strConnectionString);
                string strProcedureName = "";
                if (SPANTYPE == "INTERCITY" || SPANTYPE == "INTRACITY" || SPANTYPE == "ENTERPRISE")
                {
                    strProcedureName = strPackageName + ".GET_SPAN_BY_MZ";
                }
                else if (SPANTYPE == "FTTX")
                {
                    strProcedureName = strPackageName + ".GET_FTTX_BY_MZ ";
                }
                //else
                //{
                //    strProcedureName = strPackageName + ".GET_SPANINFO_BY_SPAN_MZ_LNK";
                //}

                List<OracleParameter> lstParameters = new List<OracleParameter>();

                OracleParameter ObjOracleParameter = new OracleParameter("PUSERTYPE", USERTYPE);
                OracleParameter ObjOracleParameter1 = new OracleParameter("POPERATIONTYPE", OPERATIONTYPE);
                OracleParameter ObjOracleParameter2 = new OracleParameter("PSPANTYPE", SPANTYPE);
                OracleParameter ObjOracleParameter3 = new OracleParameter("PMAINTZONECODE", MZONE);
                OracleParameter ObjOracleParameter4 = new OracleParameter("PSPANDATA", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);

                lstParameters.Add(ObjOracleParameter);
                lstParameters.Add(ObjOracleParameter1);
                lstParameters.Add(ObjOracleParameter2);
                lstParameters.Add(ObjOracleParameter3);
                lstParameters.Add(ObjOracleParameter4);

                dtSPAN = ObjDBObject.ExecuteDataTableProcedure(strProcedureName, lstParameters);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //throw;
                ErrorLog.HandleErrorLog(USERTYPE, "", "GetSPANByMZ", e.Message);
                /*
                 * Error(string LogType, string functionname, string msg)
                 */
                ApplicationLog.Error("Error", "GetSPANByMZ", e.Message);
            }

            return dtSPAN;
        }
```

Please suggest

Comment: obviously this isn't mysql right?

Comment: I don't know oracle well enough to identify this.

Comment: hey lalit, i finally resolved the issue with help of my team mates.. thanks for your conern mate.

Comment: @hud Ok, that's good news. So what was the issue?

Comment: there were several things, cursor was not properly handled.. and one which you mentioned the subquery which was taking too much time to execute..

Comment: @hud I would encourage you to post your resolution as an answer and mark it answered, it could help others.

Comment: @hud Okay, good luck. Stay safe!

Comment: Of course..will do. just testing whether everything else is working fine with it or not.. thanks mate.. you too stay safe